# `(void*)` usage used as function parameter instead of `struct *`

Tags: c

Is there any big difference if I use something like this:

```
void print_struct( void *ptr_to_struct )
```

instead of:

```
void print_struct( struct data *ptr_to_struct )
```

I am asking this because I just got stuck in something what I cannot understand and why it does not work in the following manner:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void print_struct( struct data *ptr_to_struct );
struct data{
    char name[ 256 ];
};

int main( void )
{
    struct data ptr;
    strcpy ( ptr.name, "George" );
    print_struct_1( &ptr);
}

void print_struct( struct data *ptr_to_struct )
{
    struct data *ptr = ptr_to_struct;
    printf("Name = %s\n", ptr->name );
}
```

I get:

```
error: ‘struct data’ declared inside parameter list will not be visible outside of this definition or declaration [-Werror]
```

But if I move:

```
void print_struct( struct data *ptr_to_struct );
```

After:

```
struct data{
    char name[ 256 ];
};
```

Compiles fine.

The thing which I do not understand is the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void print_struct( void *ptr_to_struct );
struct data{
    char name[ 256 ];
};
//void print_struct( void *ptr_to_struct );


int main( void )
{
    struct data ptr;
    strcpy ( ptr.name, "George" );
    print_struct_1( &ptr);
}

void print_struct( void *ptr_to_struct )
{
    struct data *ptr = ( struct data * )ptr_to_struct;
    printf("Name = %s\n", ptr->name );
}
```

No mater if I use:

```
void print_struct( void *ptr_to_struct );
```

Before or after:

```
struct data{
    char name[ 256 ];
};
```

The program works fine.

Why is there this difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. When you refer to an unknown `struct something` type in a function prototype, it effectively declares a new struct type. However, the new type will be local to that prototype. The new type will not be related to any identically names `struct something` type declared afterwards. For example

   ```
   void foo(struct S *p) {}
   struct S { int i; };

   int main(void) {
     struct S s;
     foo(&s); // ERROR: the pointer types are unrelated
   }
   ```

   Basically, don't do that. Don't use unknown `struct something` types in function prototypes. It is pointless. It is virtually always an indication of a typo or some other error. This is why the compiler is issuing a warning.

   Such struct types have to be declared *before* the prototype. You can rearrange your declarations (as you already tried). Or you can pre-declare the struct type

   ```
   struct data;
   void print_struct( struct data *ptr_to_struct );
   struct data{
     char name[ 256 ];
   };
   ```

   This will also work properly.
2. Declaring a function prototype with a parameter type `void *` and then defining the same function with parameter of `struct something *` type leads to undefined behavior, even if your program appears to "work fine".

Comment: So If I use it [Like this it is fine](https://ideone.com/lQKv76), or can lead to `UB` ?

Comment: @Michael B.: What you have at that link looks fine. Some `const` qualifiers are completely unjustified though.

Comment: `Some const qualifiers are completely unjustified ` Why is that? I mean The purpose there is to tell the Compiler that I am not touching that pointer or its pointed value. Or I am wrong?

Comment: @Michael B: Well, in that case make it consistent: inside your `print_struct` declare `ptr` as `const struct data *ptr`. That will also make the cast unnecessary. Currently you use that cast to cast some of your `const`s away. What's the point of using `const` if you are going to immediately cast it away anyway?

Comment: I understand now. Thank you.